# DKIM - Single host - Multiple IPs

Tags: linux, centos, email, dkim, opendkim

Trying to figure out the best practice for implementing DKIM on a single EC2 which will have multiple, elastic IPS.

```
# /etc/opendkim.conf
...
Mode                    sv
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
...

# /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
default._domainkey.example.com example.com:hp-hv-1:/etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
default._domainkey.example.com example.com:hp-hv-2:/etc/opendkim/keys/default.private

# /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
*@example.com default._domainkey.example.com
```

Then I have two DNS records:

```
hp-hv-1._domainkey.example.com TXT "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=default.txt_key_goes_here"

hp-hv-2._domainkey.example.com TXT "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=default.txt_key_goes_here"
```

For both postfix instances on the same EC2 instance, each have the following $myhostname:

```
# postfixmulti instance #1
myhostname = hp-hv-1

# postfixmulti instance #2
myhostname = hp-hv-2
```

Both postfix instances are on the same EC2 instance, so they both share the same default.private/default.txt private/public key pair, so there is no need to add more rows to KeyTable and SigningTable. As far as I can tell, I only need to add extra rows to KeyTable and SigningTable if I want to implement multiple domains (which I do not).

But when I test my DKIM settings I keep getting 'pass: neutral' responses, saying that the emails are not signed, but they are, I can see it in the log file:

```
# snippet from /var/log/maillog
Sep 25 15:15:31 service-a-4 opendkim[27420]: 5B4A3625F0: DKIM-Signature field added (s=hp-hv-1, d=example.com)
```

What am I missing?

Versions:

```
CentOS 6.5
Postfix v2.6.6
Opendkim v2.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was obviously confused, I kept thinking that "s" in the DKIM signature field was supposed to identify $myhostname from the postfix config, but actually it does not. After reading more about [DKIM key rotation](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/default/files/document/M3AAWG_DKIM_Key_Rotation_BP-2013-12.pdf), it finally donned on me, the "s" is simply the selector to use from the KeyTable, SigningTable, and DNS.

Check this:

```
# /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
#  Format: selector(1) domain:selector(2):/path/to/key
#    selector(1) is used in the /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
#    selector(2) is built into the DKIM signature for every email sent, which is used to lookup the DNS TXT entry: mail-1_r-1._domainkey.example.com
mail-1_r-1._domainkey.example.com example.com:mail-1_r-1:/etc/opendkim/keys/mail-1_r-1.private
```

And now if I want to rotate the keys I would do this:

```
# /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
#  Generate new private/public key pair, and rename accordingly
mail-1_r-1._domainkey.example.com example.com:mail-1_r-1:/etc/opendkim/keys/mail-1_r-1.private
mail-1_r-2._domainkey.example.com example.com:mail-1_r-2:/etc/opendkim/keys/mail-1_r-2.private
```

Then in the signing table:

```
# /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
*@shouttag.com mail_r-1._domainkey.example.com
*@shouttag.com mail_r-2._domainkey.example.com
```

Then for DNS entries you will have the following

```
mail_r-1.domainkey.example.com "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=mail_r-1.txt_key_goes_here"
mail_r-2.domainkey.example.com "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=mail_r-2.txt_key_goes_here"
```

These DNS entries are what is used to help validate that email was truly sent from your domain (hence Domain Key Identified Mail). Then after 7 days or so, you can remove the mail_r-1.domainkey.example.com.